# Facebook Login Using Requests error

Tags: python, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = requests.Session()
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.get("https://www.facebook.com/").content)

payload = {
"lsd":soup.find("input",{"name":"lsd"})["value"],
"email":"my_email",
"pass":"my_password",
"persistent":"1",
"default_persistent":"1",
"timezone":"300",
"lgnrnd":soup.find("input",{"name":"lgnrnd"})["value"],
"lgndim":soup.find("input",{"name":"lgndim"})["value"],
"lgnjs":soup.find("input",{"name":"lgnjs"})["value"],
"locale":"en_US",
"qsstamp":soup.find("input",{"name":"qsstamp"})["value"]
}



soup = BeautifulSoup(a.post("https://www.facebook.com/",data = payload).content)
print([i.text for i in soup.find_all("a")])
```

Im playing around with requests and have read several threads here in SO about it so I decided to try it out myself.

I am stumped by this line. `"qsstamp":soup.find("input",{"name":"qsstamp"})["value"]`
because it returns empty thereby cause an error.

however looking at chrome developer tools this `"qsstamp"` is populated what am I missing here?

the `payload` is everything shown in the form data on chrome dev tools. so what is going on?

Comment: The page `requests` gets may not be as same as you see in Chrome.

Comment: but why does `qsstamp` return empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Firebug and search for `qsstamp` gives matched results directs to: [Here](https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yF/r/A0qdgknEnD5.js)

You can see: `j.createHiddenInputs({qsstamp:u},v)`
That means `qsstamp` is dynamically generated by JavaScript.

`requests` will not run JavaScript(since what it does is to fetch that page's HTML.) You may want to use something like `dryscape` or using emulated browser like `Selenium`.

Comment: so that's why :/

been banging my head over this the past couple of hours.

Comment: I am very curious @zion how did it go? I am working on the exact same problem and is about to give up. Did u manage to login to facebook with requests?

Comment: Use things like PhantomJS or use Facebook API instead.